# Forms Authentication is locked in IIS 7

Tags: iis, iis-7

I have a dual authenticated site that is using Forms Auth in the web config of the application. On one single page I need to switch the Auth method to WindowsAuthentication to handle intranet Network login credentials. When in IIS 7 to manage the authentication method of the sigle page I am concered with the option to DISABLE FormsAuthentication is locked. I have tried numerous methods to unlock it from Feature delegation, AllowOveride in the web config and manually changing settings in the ApplicationHost file, all to no avail. I am looking for the means to remove the LOCK on the FormsAuthentication in IIS 7

Answer (score 0):

try using appcmd 
ex:

%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd unlock config /section:anonymousAuthentication
 %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd unlock config /section:windowsAuthentication